# Expandable RecyclerView: How to have different "child-rows" (which are displayed when an item is expanded) have different layouts?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use [this library project by dgreenhalgh for creating an expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view), **but my requirement is to have an *expandable* RecyclerView *with different layouts for different rows*.**

So I first wrote a small example application to test the library project. **[I am posting it here.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/obrdwdvh00b2cki/ExpandableRecyclerView%40GithubTestOne.rar)** **Now I need to make it use different layouts for different *children-rows*** - i.e. when the user clicks on an item in the list (let's call that *parent-row* for now), it is expanded to show its children-rows, like in the following screenshot.

[image]

But I need different layouts for different *child*-rows. I searched around and found [this example for "RecyclerView with Multiple Viewtype"](http://doublewong.com/2014/create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type/) quite simple and nice. So I want to do this like in the example, that is by extending the  ViewGroup...

**In this approach**, they extend a main ViewGroup with different ViewGroups (each corresponding to a layout for a row-style). Then in `getItemViewType` of the `RecyclerAdapter`, they decide what `viewtype` to return based on the `position` passed in the method, and then in `onCreateViewHolder`, decide which layout to inflate based on the `viewtype` passed.

**In my use-case, it would have been straightforward if it was the `parent-rows` that I needed the multiple layouts for**, because it is the data-list containing the data to show in the `parent-rows` which is passed to our `ExpandableRecyclerAdapter`. So in our `getItemViewType`, we can do something like

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType ( int position ) {
    int viewType;
    if ( groups.get ( position ).getImagePath () != null ) { //****groups is the list containing the data to be displayed in the recyclerview's "parent" items
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    return viewType;
}
```

where `groups` is the `ArrayList` passed to the `RecyclerViewAdapter` which contains the data to be displayed in the parent-rows.

**This `ArrayList` contains objects of type `ParentObject` (actually a class I wrote which extends `ParentObject`). Inside this class, a method by the name of `getChildObjectList` returns a `List<ChildObject>` which contains the data to be displayed in the child-rows.**

QUESTION:

**So I can not have a `getItemViewType` and the entire functionality of the `RecyclerViewAdapter` inside my class which extends `ParentObject`, which is (creating) and returning the `ArrayList` which contains the data to be displayed in the child-rows.**

**So how should I go about it?**